# How to filter an array using matching objects from another array and push it to a new array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following data array that I wanna filter by company name/names.

```
data = [
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 1",
         "symbol":"one"
      },
      "description":"test",
      "status":"Pending"
   },
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 2",
         "symbol":"two"
      },
      "description":"test",
      "status":"Pending"
   },
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 3",
         "symbol":"three"
      },
      "description":"test",
      "status":"Pending"
   },
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 1",
         "symbol":"four"
      },
      "description":"testrr",
      "status":"Pending"
   }
]
```

```
filterBy = ["Company 1", "Company 3"]
```

**Expected Result**

```
filteredData = [
   {
      "companyName":"Company 1",
      "matchingData":[
         {
            "company":{
               "name":"Company 1",
               "symbol":"one"
            },
            "description":"test",
            "status":"Pending"
         },
         {
            "company":{
               "name":"Company 1",
               "symbol":"four"
            },
            "description":"testrr",
            "status":"Pending"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "companyName":"Company 3",
      "matchingData":[
         {
            "company":{
               "name":"Company 3",
               "symbol":"three"
            },
            "description":"test",
            "status":"Pending"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**Attempted**

using the the following attempt I am getting all the matching objects instead of each match individually

```
const result = data.filter((obj) => filterBy.includes(obj.company.name));
let expectedResult = []
 filterBy.forEach((e, i )=> {
      let d = {companyName:e[i], matchingData: result}
      expectedResult .push(d)
    });
```

...................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: (After your edit - which is a bummer since you already got two answers on a totally different sample an desired output...) I would suggest for a far better output, and that's an Objectwhere the keys are the actualy company names (since those are anyways unique!) `{"Company 1": [{}, {}], "Company 3": [{}]}` the code necessary to create such an output would be a nobrainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you changed the Question desired output on the fly - I guess you're not strictly enforcing that exact output - therefore here's a **far better one**.

I would suggest for a far better output, and that's an **Object** - where the keys are the actually company names (since those are anyways unique!) `{"Company 1": [{}, {}], "Company 3": [{}]}` the code necessary to create such an output would be a nobrainer thanks to [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const data = [{"company":{"name":"Company 1","symbol":"one"},"description":"test","status":"Pending"},{"company":{"name":"Company 2","symbol":"two"},"description":"test","status":"Pending"},{"company":{"name":"Company 3","symbol":"three"},"description":"test","status":"Pending"},{"company":{"name":"Company 1","symbol":"four"},"description":"testrr","status":"Pending"}];

const filterBy = ["Company 1", "Company 3"];

const filteredData = data.reduce((ob, data) => {
  const n = data.company.name;
  if (filterBy.includes(n)) {
    if (!ob[n]) ob[n] = [];
    ob[n].push(data);
  }
  return ob;
}, {});

console.log(filteredData); // {"Company 1": [{..}, {..}], "Company 3", [{..}]}
```

The beauty of the above is that later you can easily extract the desired list using:

```js
const items_of_comp_1 = filteredData["Company 1"];
console.log(items_of_comp_1); // [{...}, {...}]
```

Or if you want to loop the `filteredData` Object you can do it super easily using:  [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) methods!

---

***Old answer before your edit***

You were pretty close, but .forEach() and .map() are not meant to create subsets. .filter() is also out of the game since you want a slightly modified output. Therefore use .reduce():

- Use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce an array to a filtered but modified set of items
- Use Array.prototype.includes() (which you already do use) to check whether an array includes a specific item

```js
const data = [{"company":{"name":"Company 1","symbol":"one"},"description":"test","status":"Pending"},{"company":{"name":"Company 2","symbol":"two"},"description":"test","status":"Pending"},{"company":{"name":"Company 3","symbol":"three"},"description":"test","status":"Pending"}];
const filterBy = ["Company 1", "Company 3"]

const filteredData = data.reduce((a, matchingData) => {
  const companyName = matchingData.company.name;
  if (filterBy.includes(companyName)) a.push({companyName, matchingData});
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: You are beyond awesome! really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The `matchingData` property in each output item needs to be not the `result`, which is the whole filtered array, but an array with a single element in it, where that element is the filtered item being iterated over.

You can also use `.map` instead of `.push` to make things a bit cleaner.

```js
data = [
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 1",
         "symbol":"one"
      },
      "description":"test",
      "status":"Pending"
   },
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 2",
         "symbol":"two"
      },
      "description":"test",
      "status":"Pending"
   },
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 3",
         "symbol":"three"
      },
      "description":"test",
      "status":"Pending"
   }
]
filterBy = ["Company 1", "Company 3"]

const result = data
  .filter((obj) => filterBy.includes(obj.company.name))
  .map(item => ({
    companyName: item.company.name,
    matchingData: [item]
  }));
console.log(result);
```

If multiple items in the input array may have the same company, and those same companies should be grouped in the output - eg

```
filteredData = [
   {
      "companyName":"Company 1",
      "matchingData":[
          <some company 1 object>,
          <some other company 1 object>,
```

then you'll need to be a bit more elaborate. Make an object whose keys are the `companyName` and values are the arrays.

```js
data = [
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 1",
         "symbol":"one"
      },
      "description":"test",
      "status":"Pending"
   },
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 2",
         "symbol":"two"
      },
      "description":"test",
      "status":"Pending"
   },
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 3",
         "symbol":"three"
      },
      "description":"test",
      "status":"Pending"
   }
]
filterBy = ["Company 1", "Company 3"]

const filtered = data.filter((obj) => filterBy.includes(obj.company.name));
const grouped = {};
for (const item of filtered) {
  const { name } = item.company;
  grouped[name] ??= [];
  grouped[name].push(item);
}
const result = Object.entries(grouped).map(
  ([companyName, matchingData]) => (
    { companyName, matchingData }
  ));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I just edited my data: 'Company 1' might have more than one matching item, and I want them all in the same array. Sorry for not explaining it correctly

Comment: Then use the code in the second part of the answer

Answer (score -1):

Here is your code I filter for company 1 and company 3

https://codepen.io/tmixab/pen/poPrxWJ

```
data = [
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 1",
         "symbol":"one"
      },
      "description":"test",
      "status":"Pending"
   },
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 2",
         "symbol":"two"
      },
      "description":"test",
      "status":"Pending"
   },
   {
      "company":{
         "name":"Company 3",
         "symbol":"three"
      },
      "description":"test",
      "status":"Pending"
   }
]

filterBy = ["Company 1", "Company 3"];

const result = data.filter((obj) => filterBy.includes(obj.company.name));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));

/*
let expectedResult = []
 filterBy.forEach((e, i )=> {
      let d = {companyName:e[i], matchingData: result}
      expectedResult.push(d)
    });
*/
```